# c:forEach not working in tomcat 7

Tags: jsf-2, foreach, tomcat7

I created simple page using **c:forEach** tag. Its working in tomcat 6. But `not working tomcat 7`.  Developed simple web application using JSF 2.0.

I run my code in tomcat 6. its working.
I deployed in tomcat 7. Its not working. c:forEach tag result not appearing.

**welcomeJSF.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<f:view>
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      </head>
      <body>
            <h:form id="forEachForm" binding="#{simpleDemo.initForm}">
            <c:forEach items="#{simpleDemo.userBeanList}" var="userBean"  varStatus="status">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="1"> 

                    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.userName}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.role}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </c:forEach>
</h:form>
 </body></html></f:view>
```

I used the following jar

```
1. jsf-api.jar
2. jsf-impl.jar
3. jstl-1.2.jar
4. standard.jar
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/welcomeJSF.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>simpleDemo</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.tomcat.foreach.SimpleDemo</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>    
</faces-config>
```

**SimpleDemo.java**

```
package com.tomcat.foreach;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;

public class SimpleDemo
{
private HtmlForm initForm;
private List<UserBean> userBeanList = new ArrayList<UserBean>();    

public HtmlForm getInitForm()
{
    userBeanList.clear();

    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setUserName("jack");
    userBean.setRole("sample Role");
    userBeanList.add(userBean);

    userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setUserName("adminuser");
    userBean.setRole("Admin Role");
    userBeanList.add(userBean);

    userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setUserName("Test User");
    userBean.setRole("Test role");
    userBeanList.add(userBean);

    return initForm;
}

public void setInitForm(HtmlForm initForm){
    this.initForm = initForm;
}
public List<UserBean> getUserBeanList(){
    return userBeanList;
}
public void setUserBeanList(List<UserBean> userBeanList){
    this.userBeanList = userBeanList;
}  }
```

**UserBean.java**

```
package com.tomcat.foreach;

public class UserBean
{
private String userName;
private String role;

public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName){
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getRole(){
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role){
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

Help me,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you are developing a JSF 1.2 application) Otherwise, iIf you are using JSF 2.0, why do you define beans in `faces-config`? Why did you choose JSP as a view technology? And, finally, what is the reason of using `<c:forEach>` instead of the more appropriate `<ui:repeat>`?

Comment: Thanks skuntsel for your response. Already i developed project JSF2.0 + richfaces 3.3.3 final version. Before that i deployed tomcat 6. Now i am deploying tomcat7. all pages are working fine. Few pages i used  c:forEach tag.

Comment: Last but not least, the managed bean name might not be resolved. Please respect the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and decapitalize thge first word of a managed bean, escpecially if you don't name it (hence, making a bean visible by `decapitalizedBean`).

Comment: In the end, why do you use form binding? You would either manage your form programmatically from a backing bean or let JSF manage it for you, thus deleting your binding from the form component.

Comment: So, what is happening in `simpleDemo.initForm`? Post your managed bean here so that we can answer.

Comment: Now i post the managed bean content. here i am trying small sample jsp page. That why i am not giving more important to the naming convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `standard.jar`. It's from JSTL 1.1 and conflicting with your JSTL 1.2.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with form binding in your code (you do not create your form programmatically) and your form definition in your view, so removal of binding will solve most of your problems. The rest is metioned in comments and in this answer.

1. *The view*

First of all, there is no need to use the form binding. JSF is designed to simplify development, so use its features. So, your form will be defined in your view completely. Next, your usage of `<c:forEach>` is strange here. It must work in your code, but when your view grows it might cause subtle and hard-to-debug problems of the notorious *view build time vs view render time* problems. For excellent elaboration, consult [**Jstl in jsf2 facelets makes sense**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) answer by BalusC here, remembering that `<c:forEach>` is a JSTL taghandler and `<ui:repeat>` is a JSF UI component.

```
<h:form id="forEachForm" >
    <ui:repeat value="#{simpleDemo.userList}" var="user">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="1"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{userBean.userName}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{userBean.role}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

But note that your view with `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` would also work.

2. *The model*

Note that `User` is not a managed bean, but your model data class (`@Entity` or POJO). Your managed bean (which you decided to put in session scope) will thus be holding current users in a list.

I recommend turning to annotations for declaration of managed beans, but, of course, you are free to define them in a good old `faces-config.xml`.

Also, the business method in `getForm()` is a bad practice. It should be better done either in `@PostConstruct`, or upon `preRederView` event / page `action`, but not in a getter method.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SimpleDemo {

    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SimpleDemo() {
        //mock data
        User user1 = new User("User 1", "Role 1");
        User user2 = new User("User 2", "Role 2");
        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);
    }

    //getters and setters for list

}

public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String role;

    //constructors, setters, getters

}
```

With this setup your form will be populated with a list of users upon retrieval of information (as it would be fully initialized in a constructor of a bean).